# What is the purpose of .rodata.cst16 costants in NASM?

Tags: gcc, reverse-engineering, nasm

I have disassembled various C object files compiled with gcc x64 in NASM, and in the section `.rodata.cst16` there are always declared some global variables that are all the same

```
SECTION .rodata.cst16  

    LC4:                                                    ; dword
            dd 80000000H, 00000000H                         ; 0000 _ -0.0 0.0 
            dd 00000000H, 00000000H                         ; 0008 _ 0.0 0.0 

    LC5:                                                    ; dword
            dd 80000000H, 00000000H                         ; 0000 _ -0.0 0.0 
            dd 00000000H, 00000000H                         ; 0008 _ 0.0 0.0
```

Here a sample of use of these constants in the code sections

```
 vmovss  xmm4, dword [rel LC4]
```

are all used with `rel` keyword with AVX mov operation `vmovss`in the same way

and I don'd understand the reason. why are needed these global constants used in this strange way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're constants.

More details... ummm, `.rodata.cst16` sort of implies **READ-ONLY** **Constants** **16 bytes wide**.

Often it is easier and quicker to load a register from a memory address than from a literal value.  Add to this the fact that these are used in concert with the xmms registers and it makes more sense.

Loading the xmms register with one of these constants is likely faster than trying to load a bunch of zeros into the various 'slots' of the xmms register.

I've done this sort of thing myself in my code, it's easier, and it's also like putting 'magic numbers' into a constant, rather than sprinkling all over your code.

Kinda like this:

```
#define NUMBER_LIONS 27
const int NUMBER_TIGERS = 23;
const float NUMBER_BEARS = 4.2f;
...
  double animal_salad = (double)(NUMBER_LIONS + NUMBER_TIGERS) / NUMBER_BEARS;
...
  printf("Oh My!\n");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know that are read-ony constants but I havent understod how I shoud read the constants.  what's meaning the constants `LC4`? and what's meaning `vmovss  xmm4, dword [rel LC4]`

Comment: `LC4` - random/sequential __label__ generated by ndisassem, `vmovss xmm4, dword [rel LC4]`... the instruction at that location.  uh.. vector move _some type_ from dword at relative location LC4 into xmm4 register.  Don't use the vmovss instruction much, don't remember exactly. I'm not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: If i have understod rip relative use the address of memory declared as costant to made the istruction in the code position independent. but I haven't understod why there are 4 hex values labeled as a single constant. e.g. 80000000H in decimal is 2147483648 the others 00000000H are all 0... why?

Comment: Because the xmm registers are 128 bits wide... requiring 16 bytes to load values.  Look up info on `xmm registers`, they're vector registers, able to work with multiple values at once.  Perhaps also look up `vector registers`, `x86_64 assembly`.

Comment: ok, but these values represent a memory address randomly generated, or is there something special at these values? in all 64 bit decompiled assembly that I have seen there is always a read only global constant with exactly these values, used with some avx instruction in the same way

Comment: these values represent a number or constant that is frequently used.  Loading a 16 byte value into an xmm register is tedious, so this constant makes it into a single instruction (vmovss).

Comment: is there any way to convert this value to understand exactly what constant? (in the original c code decompiled I don't use any string, only constants that I use are 0 and 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56083/discussion-between-lornix-and-andreaf).